# Windows module containing the standard windows cursors (i.e IDC_ARROW)

Tags: winapi, mouse-cursor

Does anyone have an idea in what modules I can find the standard windows cursors?

or does anyone have an idea how to save a cursur (HCURSOR) to a file (*.cur)

Answer (score 0):

User32.dll contain a number of system cursors and other resources